# Where In select (from single field)

Tags: mysql

```
"SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta 
          WHERE post_id ='$id' 
          AND meta_key = '_product_image_gallery'"
```

Returns `94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105`

So i thought that the following would return all the rows where the id is in the above set but in fact it only returns row `94`

```
"SELECT guid,post_title FROM wp_posts 
    WHERE ID IN
         (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta 
          WHERE post_id ='$id' 
          AND meta_key = '_product_image_gallery'
         )"
```

Anyone see why?

Comment: Are you sure you have wp_posts with the other meta_values ? just try `SELECT guid,post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE ID = 95` and see if there is some data.

Comment: I would modify the question to show that the inner SELECT returns a single row with one value: "94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105". Otherwise it is mistakenly thought as 12 different rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns only row 94 because the coercion of the string "94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105" to integer results in 94.

It is as if your SQL was:

```
SELECT guid,post_title FROM wp_posts 
WHERE ID IN ("94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105")
```

Notice that there is only one string value in the IN clause, not 12 integers.

Comment: Ok, all 12 rows were returned ?

Comment: What is the type of meta_value column in wp_postmeta? What is the type of ID column in wp_posts?

Comment: just to reiterate, `94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105` is a string in a single field

Comment: Ahhh.. well that changes everything :) I will update my answer

Comment: ok, looks like i might be able to do something with substring_index thanks